# Spyder environment and Anaconda prompt point to different interpreters

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I use Spyder environment for learning Python. I installed `pyperclip` module using pip in Anaconda prompt (conda couldn't find it) and everything works just fine in Spyder but when I try to run script using Anaconda Prompt, it cannot find the imported module.

So far, I tried to list modules using `conda list` (pyperclip is there), changing the PATH variable (variable for my user now points to folder with scripts, system PATH variable to Anaconda3 folder). I found out after running `sys.executable` in both (Spyder and Anaconda prompt - after going to `python` first) that Spyder points to C:\MyPath\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe' whereas Anaconda prompt points to C:\MyPath\Anaconda3\python.exe'.

Then I tried to set Spyder's interpreter to C:\...\python.exe but it seems like it ignores it.

I think I'm missing something elementary here.

Comment: is the pyperclip installed in a different environment? check where the pacakge is installed